# Bash conditional statement

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I realize this is probably a really simple problem, but I can't figure out why this isn't working. I'm attempting to check if a folder is larger than 35GB and if so, remove all files that are older than 3 days in it.

With this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAX=35000000000
if [ $(du -sb ~/MEGA | cut -f1) \> $MAX ] then
   find ~/MEGA/* -mtime +3 -exec rm -fr {} \;
fi
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
 syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon or a line jump before the `then` keyword.  Beware also that Bash uses `>` to compare strings, not numbers.  For numeric comparison you should be using either `-gt` or the Bash specific `((` arithmetic expression evaluator.  For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAX=35000000000
if (( $(du -sb ~/MEGA | cut -f1) > $MAX ))
then
   find ~/MEGA/* -mtime +3 -exec rm -fr {} \;
fi
```

Reference: [Bash conditional constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)

Comment: Just to clarify the difference between string vs. numeric comparison: `[ 5 \> 35000000000 ]` would evaluate as true, because "5" comes after "3".

Comment: Can double parenthesis be used for strings as well? Or only numerical operations?

Comment: Use `(( ))` only for arithmetic.  For strings or other general cases, Bash has its specific `[[ ]]` test operator which handles some empty string cases more gracefully than the traditional `[ ]`

Answer (score 1):

Change `if [ $(du -sb ~/MEGA | cut -f1) \> $MAX ] then`
to

```
if (( $(du -sb ~/MEGA | cut -f1) > MAX )); then
```

format of if statement:

```
if condition;then
something
fi
```

Or

```
if condition
then
something
fi
```

Or

```
if condition;then something;fi
```

Note:

1. You can merge multiple lines using `;` between them
2. You can drop the `$` from `$MAX` inside the arithmetic if statement

Answer (score 0):

Bash error messages are sometimes misleading. You forgot the semicolon before the then.

```
#!/bin/bash
MAX=35000000000
if [ $(du -sb ~/MEGA | cut -f1) -gt $MAX ]; then
find ~/MEGA/* -mtime +3 -exec rm -fr {} \;
fi
```